# can we use row and col-md-12 in same div ? or it should be in parent child divs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get clarify if we can use

or we have to use

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check this out, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be `columns` inside a `row` it means in same element `row` and `columns` are **not possible**.

You must have `columns` inside a `row` in `bootstrap` i.e. it must be parent(`row`) child(`col`) divs.

Possible:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  </div>
</div>
```

Not Possible:

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
  <div class="abc">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i jest want to give try if we can use in single now i understand.

Answer (score 1):

First understand the css of `row` and `col`

**ROW**

```
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
```

**COL-MD-12**

```
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
float: left;
width:100%
```

Since row has `margin-right` and `margin-left` -15px and `col` has `padding-right` and `padding-left` 15px, no use of having both classes to a same element.

Bootstrap is arranged in the manner of `container` > `row` > `col`. Don't violate the pattern, then you will be in trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the more clarification.

Comment: If you found this answer is useful please upvote it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use col-md-12 as child element of row element

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
     Content Here...
  </div>
</div>
```